# User receive push notification if only signed in for web

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to firebase and I am trying to implement a system where user will receive a push notification only if he/she is logged in. I am trying to implement like

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if(user){
            console.log(user);
            console.log('logged in');
            signInButton.style.display = "none";
            signOutButton.removeAttribute('hidden');


            messaging.getToken()
                .then(function(currentToken) {
                    console.log(currentToken);
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
                });


            messaging.onTokenRefresh(function() {
                messaging.getToken()
                    .then(function(refreshedToken) {
                        console.log(refreshedToken);
                        console.log('Token refreshed.');
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
                    });
            });

            messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
                console.log('onMessage: ', payload);
            })
        }else{
            console.log('not logged in');
        }


    });
```

If user logged in then he will get payload message, otherwise not, but still getting notification(if app is in foreground) for logged out user.

Comment: Your snippet is not helpful. you are just logging things and not wiring any logic. It's also not very clear. Are you doing user targeted push notifications? Or are you sending 2 types of notifications: one for logged in users and another for logged out users?

Comment: I am trying to send notification for logged in users

Comment: Could you solve it? Can you share your code if you could solve it?